# iOS: Setting up a Mach exception handler without interfering with LLDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unix, signals

I'm using the library called [CwlPreconditionTesting](https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlPreconditionTesting/) which is used to test Swift assertions. It uses Mach exceptions handler API to catch exceptions that's available on iOS and OS X.

The library works well in simulators, but devices aren't supported by it. The reason for this is that on devices, the Swift assert functions (e.g. [fatalError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538698-fatalerror)) crash with `EXC_BREAKPOINT` exception type, which is also the exception type the debugger uses when someone puts a breakpoint somewhere and the debugger wants to suspend the program. The underlying assembly instruction is `brk`.

I wanted to add device tests support to the library, but after setting up the exception handler, if the debugger reaches a breakpoint I added manually, the debugger just hangs. To bypass this, I tried to make the exception handler forward the handling of the exception to the debugger.

When I implement an exception handler, if it returns with a failure (i.e. anything other than `KERN_SUCCESS`), the kernel should forward it to the next exception handler in line, the debugger in my case. I didn't find any official documentation on this, but it says so [here](https://gist.github.com/rodionovd/01fff61927a665d78ecf#file-mach_exceptions-cpp-L248) and in a piece of code from [Mike Ash's blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-01-11-mach-exception-handlers.html):

```
    // Handle EXCEPTION_DEFAULT behavior
    kern_return_t catch_mach_exception_raise (mach_port_t exception_port,
                                               mach_port_t thread,
                                               mach_port_t task, 
                                               exception_type_t exception,
                                               mach_exception_data_t code,
                                               mach_msg_type_number_t codeCnt)
    {
        // Do smart stuff here.
        fprintf(stderr, "My exception handler was called by exception_raise()\n");

        // Inform the kernel that we haven't handled the exception, and the
        // next handler should be called.
        return KERN_FAILURE;
    }
```

Even if I always return `KERN_FAILURE`, the debugger hangs when I pause at a breakpoint. Here's a screenshot from the Variables View in Xcode, which loads indefinitely: [image: Debugger hangs]

Is there a way to set up an exception handler and live in peace with LLDB?